# How to use Amazon S3 as Moodle Data Root

Tags: amazon-s3, moodle

I am trying to move my moodledata folder content into Amazon S3. i didnt found any document (or guide) to configure this setup. 
I am using MOODLE 3.3 STABLE build version. 
Can anyone help me to setup this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use s3fs and mount it on your webserver.
I suggest to use local directory (for performance) to:

cache, localcache and sessions